# Firebase locally is pointing to cloud

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I created a nodejs/express backend app and I added `firebase-admin` to just validate if the user is logged in in the frontend.

The `login` logic is from firebase too, but is managed in the frontend.

So, when I log in locally I grab the token and try to use it in Postman. But for some reason it says that the user doesn't exist. What I notice was that the backend is getting the users from the cloud and not from my local, because when I grab the token from the cloud app, it recognise the user.

This is how I configure `firebase-admin`:

```js
// config/firebase-config.js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require('../serviceAccount.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

module.exports = admin;
```

this is my middleware:

```js
// middlewares/validateToken.js
const admin = require('../config/firebase-config');

exports.validateToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
      return res.status(401).send({error: 'Remember to include the Authorization header'});
    }
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);

    if (!decodedToken) {
      return res.status(401).send({error: 'Invalid token'});
    }

    req.user = decodedToken.email;

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send({error: error});
  }
};
```

and just in case, this is the frontend logic:

```js
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email.trim().toLowerCase(), this.password)
  .then(async () => {
    this.currentUser = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
    await this.$store.dispatch('setCurrentUser', this.currentUser)
    let userProfile = await api
      .returnUserProfileInformation({uid: this.currentUser.uid})
      .then(resp => resp.data.data);
    await this.$store.commit('SET_USER', userProfile.user)
    if (this.isAuthenticated && this.role === 'admin') this.$router.push('/admin')
    if (this.isAuthenticated && this.role === 'user') this.$router.push('/user')
  })
```

I tried generating a new `serviceAccountKey.json` file from firebase but still had this issue

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "it says that the user doesn't exist".  Please edit the question down to the specific line of code that isn't working the way you expect, along with any specific error messages that you can copy from your logs.

Comment: It's also not clear how your frontend is invoking your backend and passing required data to it. Your frontend is invoking some api called `returnUserProfileInformation`, but it's not evident how that maps to your backend `validateToken` function that you're showing.  Please also provide a complete set of code that anyone can use to reproduce the problem as you observe it.